# redirect all youtube video requests to a specific one

Tags: tcp, microsoft-ftmg-2010, traffic-shaping

I'm on an IT team in my company and I would like to block youtube to users. I don't want to just deny access to the whole youtube domain, but only to replace the .flv/.mp4 request with the one that I want. That way, if someone tries to watch youtube videos on the network, He'll get a video of why using our expensive bandwidth for pleasure is a no-no.

I thought about using a packet manipulation program and just replace the video ID with something that I want, but I didn't manage to do it right.

Comment: Heh. That's actually kinda clever.

Comment: What firewall are you using?

Comment: I'm using TMG Forefront 2010 Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best bet is to use a transparent proxy to intercept and redirect requests to your video. It's not for the average Joe but being on an IT team I have faith you can make it work with the existing howtos and tutorials. I did, and I'm just a hobbyist admin/programmer :).

I accomplished it with Squid and iptables.

Edit: What I did was test out this upside down internet setup[0]. Once I'd familiarized myself with that process I tweaked the scripts to accomplish what it was I wanted to accomplish. I think for your purposes all you would need to modify is the redirection script. Hope that helps.

[0] http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pete/upside-down-ternet.html

Comment: Can you add more details.  Some links to existing howtos you mentioned.  You say you did something with squid, please add some details.

Comment: Expanded to include the link that I used to get up and running.